# Mulesoft - Build JSON List dynamically

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-esb

I am a Mulesoft newbie trying to dynamically add data to a JSON list according to the payload but currently I am stuck on it.

Below is an example of what I pretend to return:

```
{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "Example A",
    "languages": [
        {
            "code": "en",
            "label": "English",
            "translatedName": "Example A"
        }
    ]
},

{
    "id": "2",
    "name": "Example B",
    "languages": [
        {
            "languageCode": "nl",
            "translatedName": "Voorbeeld B"
        },
        {
            "languageCode": "fr",
            "translatedName": "Exemple B"
        }
    ]
}
```

As you can see, the languages depend on the name (Example A has 1 language, Example B has 2).

Am I able to build a map, or a function, in order to return the correct languages?

Best regards and thank you in advance!

Comment: what is the input from which you build that list?

Comment: I'm not sure if I fully understood your question. There is no input, it is a GET method. I query an object on Salesforce and return the list of records on the desired format.

Comment: Then the list of records is the input and what you shown is the expected JSON format, though it is not valid JSON. Probably you missed to make it an arrray by missing adding [ and ]. You didn't explain where the languages come from.